# Defining mixed element in XSD allowing "nesting"

Tags: xml, xsd

I am facing the following problem. I need to create an XSD schema of my XML file. Let's say that I have several "Conversation Objects" nodes:

- Message
- End
- Effect

which are simple elements that I am able to describe in my XSD. Then I have a special one called:

- yesOrNoAnswer

This kind of element has the following structure:

```
<yesOrNoAnswer actor="" bar="" points="" percentage=""> message text
    <yes>
    ...
    </yes>
    <no>
    ...
    </no>
</yesOrNoAnswer>
```

Inside those "yes" and "no" nodes I can use repeatedly any of the simple "Conversation Objects" defined at the beginning, or also the "yesOrNoAnswer" node, allowing nesting in as many levels as I want. How can I define the whole "yesOrNoAnswer" node in XSD (including attributes, text, "yes" and "no" nodes) ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

This XSD will represent the constraints you describe and validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:group name="ConversationObjectGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="Message"/>
      <xs:element name="End"/>
      <xs:element name="Effect"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:element name="yesOrNoAnswer" type="YesOrNoAnswerType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="YesOrNoAnswerType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="yes" type="yesOrNoType"/>
      <xs:element name="no" type="yesOrNoType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="actor"/>
    <xs:attribute name="bar"/>
    <xs:attribute name="points"/>
    <xs:attribute name="percentage"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="yesOrNoType" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:group ref="ConversationObjectGroup"/>
      <xs:element ref="yesOrNoAnswer"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question if possible:

what about if one of the "Conversation Objects" is not that simple and has his own definition like the "YerOrNoAnswer" node? For example the "End" node is defined like this:

`<xs:element name="END" />
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="completedMission" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="retry" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>`

Can I define it in the same way (or similar) you defined the "yesOrNoAnswer" node and then reference it in the mixed complex type? ps: sorry for the bad indentation

Comment: It sounds like you're on track for applying this answer to your full situation.  If you encounter a specific issue whose resolution is unclear, post a new question with the example formated better than can be done in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I just did it, if you want to take a look you can find the link at the bottom of this comment. But in any case thanks a lot for your help cause it has been really useful for me and my project!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695542/defining-mixed-element-in-xsd-allowing-nesting